# Creating Shortcut using .Net

Tags: .net, shortcut

I would like to create a shortcut on the desktop using VBScript code. I have a virtual Drive in my computer. (Virtual Drive is like G drive) I want this shortcut to explore that Drive directly. For this I find out that Shortcut with following string as a TargetPath would work for me:

C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /n,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}::{89214D20-CAC1-4A33-8DF4-BD9D18A996B9}

While creating shortcut using vb script I need to enclose above string in " ", which don't work for me. I need to delete " " from the Target of the created Shortcut only then it works. Is there any way so that I can create shortcut programmatically, that can explore the virtual drive (available in my system). I need to get it in Vista OS.

Regards
Sumeet Nandan Garg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am generting .lnk file programmatically now using Win32 method i.e. (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut() to create the Shortcut file. And it works like charm. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 3):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=create+shortcut+programmatically) gives a lot of interesting result. For example, [this](http://www.msjogren.net/dotnet/eng/samples/dotnet_shelllink.asp) - with P/Invoke calls, seems to be an answer. (this is for your post tag `.NET`)

[Here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1088541&page=1) an example for VBScript:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set link= shell.CreateShortcut("Explorer.lnk")
link.TargetPath = "c:\windows\explorer.exe"
link.Save
```

Comment: Seems like I am not able to put the exact situation I am facing. I need to set TargetPath with no quotes (") programmatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "no quotes"? What problem with it? Do you have some string variable?

Comment: I need to put this in Target of the Shortcut:

C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /n,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\::{89214D20-CAC1-4A33-8DF4-BD9D18A996B9}

That too without enclosing in ".

Comment: First and last quotes means only string variable and will not be put in target shortcut target

Comment: when I check the property of the shortcut file manually. I found that the above string is enclosed with ". Hence, I have to remove them explicitly get it working.

Comment: And does it was not working, while having quotes in properties??

All time I saw such situation, all was working fine, quotes was used just for paths with spaces escaping.

Comment: Yes.. with quotes it is not working. Infact, with quotes ,it is giving error on Apply.

Comment: I understood! Windows threats string in quotes as complete path. So it must be: "c:\windows\explorer.exe" /n,::..

Comment: Yes.. but while creating shortcut programmatically how can I set this value as TargetPath without enclosing in Quotes? This is my main issue.

Comment: I have no such problem in Windows 7. What is your OS? I will try it also in XP SP3 soon.